# C#: How do I build the NReadability library?

Tags: c#, build

I am trying to build the NReadability library which is found [here](https://github.com/marek-stoj/NReadability). When I run the build file it returns an error saying that `nant` is not a recognized command. Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: Any reason why you don't simply open up the `*.sln` file? Or use `msbuild *.sln`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an NReadability.sln solution file under \SRC\NReadability that builds the project correctly for me in vs.

Otherwise, download and install [nant](http://nant.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Thus is because the build command uses a build tool called nant (similar to the java one called ant).

You can download it from [here](http://nant.sourceforge.net/).